# Run multiple projects via one script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible - run multiple projects via one script?
For example, I have one project for front, and one for back - try run them something like this:

```
cd ~/frontend && npm start && cd ~/backend/ && rails s
```

but in terminal starts only one app, front in this case

Comment: Do you know how to start a program *in the background?*

Comment: No, going to google it right now, thanks)